# value not getting set to the variable correctly

Tags: php

I am trying to set a variable with a password. And the last two characters are not getting applied to the variable.
XXXXXXX is the beginning of the password

```
$pass = ']-<X';
```

Above is the last 4 characters.  For some reason the

```
$pass = 'Testing -<X this thing.';
```

results with Testing -

I can't find any reference to this, can someone help, I can't change the password.

Comment: the browser you are viewing it in is trying to render it as a tag.  You can probably see it in console, or it least see its string length if you var_dump it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably echo'ing it without html encoding it. This means the browser will see the `<` as the start of a new tag. Try this:

```
echo htmlentities($pass);
```